# Unrecognized generic parent field when subclassing a generic class without specifying the type

Tags: java, generics

Why when sub-classing a generic class **without specifying the type** every other generic type of the parent class are seen as plain type in sub classes?

For instance, the following gives error because *s* is not *Map< Integer, String>* but a plain *Map*.

```
class Foo<T> {
    protected Map<Integer, String> s;
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public Bar() {
        s.get(0).length();
    }
}
```

Of course if *Bar extends Foo< Whatever>* the error disappears.

Comment: Maybe you can use a wildcard argument?

Comment: It's not a matter of solution to a problem. I'm just interested in knowing why the compiler is unable to recognize the correct generic type.

Answer (score 4):

In the [Java Language specification, Section §4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8):

> The supertype of a class may be a raw type. Member accesses for the class are treated as normal, and **member accesses for the supertype are treated as for raw types**. In the constructor of the class, calls to super are treated as method calls on a raw type.

You are accessing a member of a raw type, so all member accesses are treated as the raw type too. This is why you get the compile time error:

> The method `length()` is undefined for the type `Object`